# How to use libconfini static callback to assign a value into class variable

Tags: c++, parsing, static, ini

I am writing a class in C++ to be used in reading an .ini file and populate all its entries into a private variable (vector iniEntries). However, in the libconfini, I noticed that we need to implement a static callback function and use its dispatcher in order to get each key=value from the .ini file.

My callback function, by using the libconfini, is shown below: (Please notice that this callback is ***static*** in the tINIParser class and it must be as required by libconfini!)

```
int tINIParser::callback(IniDispatch * dispatch, void * v_other)
{
    string data = dispatch->data;
    string value = dispatch->value;
    // Now to store into
    if (dispatch->type==INI_KEY)
    {
        // I tried this... (iniKeysTemp and iniValuesTemp are private in tINIParser and non-static but I also tried to use static)
        iniKeysTemp = data;
        iniValuesTemp = value;
        // And also this with vectors... (iniKeys and iniValues are private in tINIParser and non-static but I also tried to use static)
        iniKeys.push_back(data);
        iniValues.push_back(value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the main question is: How I can store the dispatch values into my tINIParser class variables? I am getting linking errors and compiling errors such as:

- warning: relocation against `_ZN10tINIParser13iniValuesTempB5cxx11E' in read-only section` .text'
- in function `tINIParser::callback(IniDispatch*, void*)':
- undefined reference to `tINIParser::iniKeysTemp[abi:cxx11]'
- undefined reference to `tINIParser::iniValuesTemp[abi:cxx11]'

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. But it seems that the library has a C++ class example for doing more or less what you want to do ([map.cpp](https://github.com/madmurphy/libconfini/blob/master/examples/cplusplus/map.cpp) and [map.hpp](https://github.com/madmurphy/libconfini/blob/master/examples/cplusplus/map.hpp)), why don't you start by editing that?